# How to use inproc transport with pyzmq?

Tags: python, sockets, publish-subscribe, pyzmq, inproc

I have set up two small scripts imitating a publish and subscribe procedure with pyzmq. However, I am unable to send messages over to my subscriber client using the `inproc` transport. I am able to use `tcp://127.0.0.1:8080` fine, just not inproc.

**pub_server.py**

```
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("inproc://stream")

while True:
    socket.send_string("Hello")
    time.sleep(1)
```

**sub_client.py**

```
import sys
import zmq

# Socket to talk to server
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
socket.connect("inproc://stream")

for x in range (5):
    string = socket.recv()
    print(string)
```

How can I successfully alter my code so that I'm able to use the inproc transport method between my two scripts?

**EDIT:**

I have updated my code to further reflect @larsks comment. I am still not receiving my published string - what is it that I am doing wrong?

```
import threading
import zmq

def pub():
    context = zmq.Context()
    sender = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    sender.connect("inproc://hello")
    lock = threading.RLock()

    with lock:
        sender.send(b"")

def sub():
    context = zmq.Context()
    receiver = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    receiver.bind("inproc://hello")

    pub()

    # Wait for signal
    string = receiver.recv()
    print(string)
    print("Test successful!")

    receiver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sub()
```

Comment: Folks are commonly replying that the context “should” be the same as if it’s just general practice but with inpoc:// the context MUST be the same. The zmq context is the glue to the internal zmq io thread that inproc sockets share. Inproc is not possible across different contexts. You must use a global context when using inproc.

Answer (score 8):

As the name implies, `inproc` sockets can only be used *within the same process*.  If you were to rewrite your client and server such that there were two threads in the same process you could use `inproc`, but otherwise this socket type simply isn't suitable for what you're doing.

The [documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-inproc) is very clear on this point:

> The in-process transport passes messages via memory directly between threads sharing a single ØMQ context.

**Update**

Taking a look at the updated code, the problem that stands out first is that while the documentation quoted above says "...between threads sharing a single ØMQ context", you are creating *two* contexts in your code.  Typically, you will only call `zmq.Context()` **once** in your program.

Next, you are never subscribing your subscriber to any messages, so even in the event that everything else was working correctly you would not actually receive any messages.

Lastly, your code is going to experience the [slow joiner problem](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out):

> There is one more important thing to know about PUB-SUB sockets: you do not know precisely when a subscriber starts to get messages. Even if you start a subscriber, wait a while, and then start the publisher, the subscriber will always miss the first messages that the publisher sends. This is because as the subscriber connects to the publisher (something that takes a small but non-zero time), the publisher may already be sending messages out.

The pub/sub model isn't meant for single messages, nor is it meant to be a reliable transport.

So, to sum up:

- You need to create a shared ZMQ context before you creating your sockets.
- You probably want your publisher to publish in a loop instead of publishing a single message.  Since you're trying to use `inproc` sockets you're going to need to put your two functions into separate threads.
- You need to set a subscription filter in order to receive messages.

There is an [example using `PAIR` sockets](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:mtrelay) in the ZMQ documentation that might provide a useful starting point. `PAIR` sockets are designed for coordinating threads over `inproc` sockets, and unlike pub/sub sockets they are bidirectional and are not impacted by the "slow joiner" issue.

Comment: Thanks @larsks. However, I have edited my question and included my altered script in conjunction with your answer, but I am still not receiving anything that I publish. What is it that I may be doing wrong?

Comment: I've made an update that I hope points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. what if the pub and sub are on different machines please? Also, what are some useful use cases for using pub-sub in the same machine over inproc please? Mostly, we use pub-sub over network to let clients receive updates from publishers. What is the point from this local pub-sub in the same machine?

Comment: I am not sure if we need a  subscription filter in order to receive messages? We can just subscribe to with `""` as I can tell so far.

Comment: When you 'just subscribe to ""' you are setting a subscription filter (for "all messages").

Answer (score 0):

As mention earlier by @larsks, the context object should be the same. Declare the context object globally and use it in both pub and sub functions instead of creating new ones for each.

Comment: what if the pub and sub are on different machines please?

Comment: How can two machines share same process ? Inproc is meant to work within same process. @Avv

Answer (score 0):

Zmq contexts are the only thread safe data type when using zmq and a common context must be shared between threads that use inproc transport, regardless of language. The zmq context points to where io takes place within zmq. Inproc sockets share the same event loop where other transports may (and often will) use separate io loops within separate contexts. Here’s an example for python multi threaded inproc http://zguide2.zeromq.org/py:mtrelay

Mind that zmq does io within an isolated thread pool per context. While it’s possible to increase the io thread count on a given context, loading all io into the same thread pool is not always optimal, which is the case where multiple contexts may be used.

Also note that inproc *is* possible within the same thread as long as your not using blocking socket types. There are few cases where this is practical, unit testing being the only case I can imagine.